# Tuple works with nullptr but doesnt with NULL

Tags: c++, tuples

I have the below code where std::tuple works with nullptr but not with NULL.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

int main()
{
tuple<int*> t1, t2;

t1 = std::make_tuple(NULL);
t2 = std::make_tuple(nullptr);
}
```

When compiled with C++11, the code works when nullptr is used, but it gives the below error where NULL is used.

```
In file included from tuple.cpp:2:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0/../../../../include/c++/5.4.0/tuple:447:8: error: assigning to 'int *' from incompatible type 'long'
            = std::forward<_UHead>(_Tuple_impl<_Idx, _UHead>::_M_head(__in));
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0/../../../../include/c++/5.4.0/tuple:575:36: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::_Tuple_impl<0, int *>::operator=<long>' requested here
          static_cast<_Inherited&>(*this) = std::move(__in);
                                          ^
tuple.cpp:13:8: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::tuple<int *>::operator=<long, void>' requested here
    t1 = std::make_tuple(NULL);
       ^
1 error generated.
```

Here, the type of NULL is long int and the tuple is strict enough and doesn't accept it.

How can we make it work using NULL as well, as our client says it works when used with nvcc compiler (when they use the above snippet in the CUDA code), but its not working otherwise.

Comment: Simple response would be to stop using `NULL`.  `nullptr` works in every place `NULL` works and in the places it doesn't you have bad cod that should be fixed as you are not using `NULL` correctly.

Comment: @NathanOliver Thanks. But is there a way to support in case if they still want to use NULL. I know typecasting it to int* works, but i m wondering how nvcc compiler is handling this situation as they say this error doesn't occur when used with nvcc.

Comment: NVCC could define `NULL` like `(void*)0` which would explain why it works.  It's not legal C++ but no implementation is 100% legal.

Comment: Thanks. It must be that the NULL is defined in that way in nvcc which is different from the compiler used.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How can we make it work using NULL as well

You can use either `std::make_tuple<int*>(NULL)` or simply `std::tuple<int*>(NULL)`. But prefer using `nullptr` instead.

The problem that you face is the reason why `nullptr` was introduced to the language. Prior to its introduction, the only standard null pointer literal was 0 (also 0L etc. are valid), and that is what `NULL` expands<sup>1</sup> to.

The problem is that 0 is not only a pointer literal, but also in fact an integer literal. And it is the integer nature of the literal that takes precedence in template type argument deduction and `std::make_tuple(NULL)` may result in `std::tuple<int>` or `std::tuple<long>` depending on exact definition of `NULL`. And those tuples aren't implicitly convertible to `std::tuple<int*>`.

---

<sup>1</sup> Technically, now that `nullptr` is in the language, `NULL` could expand to that as well. But that's unlikely to happen.

Comment: I wonder if it would create problems if they just changed to NULL macro to expand to std::nullptr ?  Presumably it might break some code that was using NULL as an integer value, but arguably that code was already broken.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner It's not `std::nullptr`, it's a keyword `nullptr`. As for why it wold be a problem to change `NULL`, see "Hyrum's Law". It would break any existing code that does things that assume `NULL` to be an integer such as `str[last] = NULL`. It's a stupid thing to do, but stupid code does exist.

Comment: They tried `#define NULL nullptr` in MSVS's library code base a few years back and the compiler exploded.  Unfortunately incorrect use of `NULL` is wide spread.

Comment: Why `std::make_tuple<int*>(NULL)`? The only reason to use `make_tuple` is to deduce the arguments, explicitly specifying them defeats the purpose. `std::tuple<int*>(NULL)` does the same but less convoluted...

Comment: @MaxLanghof because they used `std::make_tuple` and wanted to make it work with `NULL`. I did suggest `std::tuple<int*>(NULL)` as a simpler alternative, but neither is as good as using `nullptr`, which I recommend in the answer.

Comment: @eerorika Thanks for the explanation. In our case, std::make_tuple<int*>(NULL) might be the best option as NULL is long int.  Defining NULL to anything else might break the existing code.

Comment: @SatyanveshD `std::make_tuple(nullptr)` is a better option. Defining NULL is not an option in practice.

Comment: @SatyanveshD As mentioned, if you can write `std::make_tuple<int*>(NULL)` then you might as well write `std::tuple<int*>(NULL)`. The former has zero advantage over the latter.

Comment: @MaxLanghof Got that.  I meant using one of these is better if they want to use NULL instead of nullptr. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

One of the reasons why `nullptr` has its own type `std::nullptr_t` is that the literal `0` is special:

> [`[conv.ptr]/1`](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.ptr#1)
>
> A *null pointer constant* is an integer literal ([lex.icon]) with value zero or a prvalue of type `std​::​nullptr_­t`.
>   A null pointer constant can be converted to a pointer type; the result is the null pointer value of that type ([basic.compound]) and is distinguishable from every other value of object pointer or function pointer type. [...]

You can convert `0` (or `0l`) to any pointer type, but you can't convert `1` (or `1l`) or any other integer to any pointer type (without an explicit cast, that is).

This works fine as long as you define `NULL` as a macro for the literal (`#define NULL 0l`) and use it directly in places where this conversion is necessary. But this makes *perfect forwarding* impossible: A function (such as `std::make_tuple`) taking `T&&` will deduce the type as `long` when passed `NULL`, losing the special properties of the `0` literal.

As a solution, `nullptr` was created and given its own type `std::nullptr_t`, with implicit conversions like those of the `0` literal. This means that perfect forwarding of `nullptr` (but not `NULL`) preserves this "specialness".

**Bottom line:** Use `nullptr` instead of `NULL` (or `0`) if you want to use C++11 features (in particular perfect forwarding) like `std::make_X`.

There is no "making it work". In a standard-conforming compiler (see [`[support.types.nullptr]/2`](http://eel.is/c++draft/support.types#nullptr-2) and footnote) using `NULL` with `make_tuple` will result in this exact problem. Don't use `NULL` or don't use `make_tuple`, that's the only answer to your question.

Comment: Thanks for the details.  Yeah nullptr works, but since they were using NULL, had to ask this.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the used compiler defines the macro `NULL` as a null-pointer constant `0L`.

So in this statement

```
t1 = std::make_tuple(NULL);
```

the type of the right expression is `std::tuple<long>`.

Try to run the following demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>

int main() 
{
    auto t = std::make_tuple( NULL );

    std::cout << std::boolalpha 
              << std::is_same<std::tuple<long>, decltype( t )>::value << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
true
```

So the deduced parameter type of the tuple is `long`.

In fact this statement

```
t1 = std::make_tuple(NULL);
```

semantically is equivalent to the following code

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    int *p;
    long v = 0L;

    p = v;

    return 0;
}
```

the compiler can issue an error similar to this

```
prog.cpp:8:6: error: invalid conversion from ‘long int’ to ‘int*’ [-fpermissive]
  p = v;
      ^
```

You need explicitly to cast `NULL` to the type `int *`. For example

```
t1 = std::make_tuple( ( int * )NULL);
```

Though in any case it is better to use `nullptr`. It is the reason why the pointer literal `nullptr` was introduced in C++.

Then you are using the pointer literal `nullptr` then it is implicitly can be converted to the type `int *`. In this case the assignment is correct. Consider

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    int *p;
    std::nullptr_t v = nullptr;

    p = v;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The question is how to get it to work with `NULL`, not why it doesn't.  The OP know why it doesn't.

Comment: @molbdnilo Thanks. It is indeed a typo.:)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the example. Your first statement is true.

Answer (score 1):

Is it mandatory that t1 and t2 are objects of the same type?

a) case YES

```
t2 = std::make_tuple(static_cast<int*>(NULL));
```

b) case NO

```
std::tuple<decltype(NULL)> t2;
```

Comment: Yes in this case, i just used t1 and t2 to show the difference. I believe t2 = std::make_tuple(nullptr);  and std::tuple<decltype(NULL)> t2;  are same.  The first case should work for me. Thanks.